# HTML Page Text search and navigation without pre-embedded tags

Tags: html, search, tags, navigation

I'm looking for ideas/solutions for the following scenario:

I'm a website developer that is given 150'ish HTML pages from a 3rd party who update and re-issue the html pages from time to time.

I'm looking for a way to implement search functionality for these pages and then navigate to that location within the page.

I don't want to add navigation tags to the html pages as these would be lost when the 3rd party re-issue the html pages.

Ideally, I would like to have a search string, search the html files, then return a list of results (kinda like Google results) then when the user clicks on the link for a particular result, the page opens and navigates to the result location within the page.

I'm familiar with c#/javascript/jquery

Any ideas/suggestions to achieve this would be welcome...or confirmation that this cant be done :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't Google, Bing, and other search engines provide APIs that let you use them to index the site then use their search capabilities to show results on only your site?

Comment: They do, however the results returned only take you to the relevant page the search was found on, not to the location of the result on the page